# What is QueryInterface and IUnknown interface?

Tags: c#-4.0, com

I want to know the actual usage of [QueryInterface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78xw8kzk.aspx) and IUnknown interface.

Comment: these interfaces have nothing to do with C#. They are part of COM. You should update your tags.

Comment: Read "Essential COM" by Don Box if you are interested in details and history. Try to make questions here more specific; this is a very broad question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QueryInterface()` is a COM version of C# `as` keyword - you call `QueryInterface()` and supply an interface id and you either get success code (`S_OK`) and a valid pointer to that interface of the object or error code `E_NOINTERFACE` and null pointer which means the object doesn't implement such interface. `IUnknown` is the interface containing `QueryInterface()` and also the reference counting methods (`AddRef()` and `Release()`) which are used for COM object lifetime management. Every COM object must implement at least `IUnknown`, otherwise you simply can't `Release()` objects when you no longer need them and calling `Release()` is the only way to tell you no longer need the object.

Answer (score 1):

**QueryInterface** checks whether the object that implements this interface supports the interface specified by IID. If so, QueryInterface

1. Increments the reference count.
2. Sets the Obj parameter so that it
   points to an instance of the specified interface.
3. Returns 0 to indicate success.

If the object does not support the interface, QueryInterface returns a nonzero error code, such as E_NoInterface.

**IUnknown** is the fundamental interface in COM-Lite, as in COM.  All other COM-Lite interfaces must derive from it.

Used for Object lifetime management (when to free an object) and object self-description (how to determine object capabilities at runtime)